# GraphQL query to copy data from one server to another

Tags: graphql

I have two different endpoints with the same schema and I want to read all data from one GraphQL endpoint and write it to the other.

One of the endpoints is provided by https://graphcms.com/ service and I recently set up a GraphQL server on AWS based on https://strapi.io project. I would like to avoid manually populating the new server with the data that already exist on graphcms so I am looking to write two graphql queries - one to read all nodes from graphcms endpoint and then write it to the other endpoint.

Here is the full schema of the target server (I need to populate only the Microsite type):

```
directive @cacheControl(
  maxAge: Int
  scope: CacheControlScope
) on FIELD_DEFINITION | OBJECT | INTERFACE
enum CacheControlScope {
  PUBLIC
  PRIVATE
}

input createMicrositeInput {
  data: MicrositeInput
}

type createMicrositePayload {
  microsite: Microsite
}

input createRoleInput {
  data: RoleInput
}

type createRolePayload {
  role: UsersPermissionsRole
}

input createUserInput {
  data: UserInput
}

type createUserPayload {
  user: UsersPermissionsUser
}

scalar DateTime

input deleteMicrositeInput {
  where: InputID
}

type deleteMicrositePayload {
  microsite: Microsite
}

input deleteRoleInput {
  where: InputID
}

type deleteRolePayload {
  role: UsersPermissionsRole
}

input deleteUserInput {
  where: InputID
}

type deleteUserPayload {
  user: UsersPermissionsUser
}

input editFileInput {
  name: String
  hash: String
  sha256: String
  ext: String
  mime: String
  size: String
  url: String
  provider: String
  public_id: String
  related: [ID]
}

input editMicrositeInput {
  name: String
  url: String
  image: String
  isVideo: Boolean
  importance: Int
  location: String
  parent: ID
  children: [ID]
}

input editRoleInput {
  name: String
  description: String
  type: String
  permissions: [ID]
  users: [ID]
}

input editUserInput {
  username: String
  email: String
  provider: String
  password: String
  resetPasswordToken: String
  confirmed: Boolean
  blocked: Boolean
  role: ID
}

input FileInput {
  name: String!
  hash: String!
  sha256: String
  ext: String
  mime: String!
  size: String!
  url: String!
  provider: String!
  public_id: String
  related: [ID]
}

input InputID {
  id: ID!
}

scalar JSON

scalar Long

type Microsite {
  id: ID!
  created_at: DateTime!
  updated_at: DateTime!
  name: String
  url: String
  image: String
  isVideo: Boolean
  importance: Int
  location: String
  parent: Microsite
  children(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [Microsite]
}

input MicrositeInput {
  name: String
  url: String
  image: String
  isVideo: Boolean
  importance: Int
  location: String
  parent: ID
  children: [ID]
}

union Morph =
    UsersPermissionsMe
  | UsersPermissionsMeRole
  | Microsite
  | createMicrositePayload
  | updateMicrositePayload
  | deleteMicrositePayload
  | UploadFile
  | UsersPermissionsPermission
  | UsersPermissionsRole
  | createRolePayload
  | updateRolePayload
  | deleteRolePayload
  | UsersPermissionsUser
  | createUserPayload
  | updateUserPayload
  | deleteUserPayload
type Mutation {
  createMicrosite(input: createMicrositeInput): createMicrositePayload
  updateMicrosite(input: updateMicrositeInput): updateMicrositePayload
  deleteMicrosite(input: deleteMicrositeInput): deleteMicrositePayload
  createRole(input: createRoleInput): createRolePayload
  updateRole(input: updateRoleInput): updateRolePayload
  deleteRole(input: deleteRoleInput): deleteRolePayload
  createUser(input: createUserInput): createUserPayload
  updateUser(input: updateUserInput): updateUserPayload
  deleteUser(input: deleteUserInput): deleteUserPayload
  upload(refId: ID, ref: String, source: String, file: Upload!): UploadFile!
}

type Query {
  microsite(id: ID!): Microsite
  microsites(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [Microsite]
  files(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [UploadFile]
  role(id: ID!): UsersPermissionsRole
  roles(
    sort: String
    limit: Int
    start: Int
    where: JSON
  ): [UsersPermissionsRole]
  user(id: ID!): UsersPermissionsUser
  users(
    sort: String
    limit: Int
    start: Int
    where: JSON
  ): [UsersPermissionsUser]
  me: UsersPermissionsMe
}

input RoleInput {
  name: String!
  description: String
  type: String
  permissions: [ID]
  users: [ID]
}

input updateMicrositeInput {
  where: InputID
  data: editMicrositeInput
}

type updateMicrositePayload {
  microsite: Microsite
}

input updateRoleInput {
  where: InputID
  data: editRoleInput
}

type updateRolePayload {
  role: UsersPermissionsRole
}

input updateUserInput {
  where: InputID
  data: editUserInput
}

type updateUserPayload {
  user: UsersPermissionsUser
}

scalar Upload

type UploadFile {
  id: ID!
  created_at: DateTime!
  updated_at: DateTime!
  name: String!
  hash: String!
  sha256: String
  ext: String
  mime: String!
  size: String!
  url: String!
  provider: String!
  public_id: String
  related(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [Morph]
}

input UserInput {
  username: String!
  email: String!
  provider: String
  password: String
  resetPasswordToken: String
  confirmed: Boolean
  blocked: Boolean
  role: ID
}

type UsersPermissionsMe {
  _id: ID!
  username: String!
  email: String!
  confirmed: Boolean
  blocked: Boolean
  role: UsersPermissionsMeRole
}

type UsersPermissionsMeRole {
  _id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
  type: String
}

type UsersPermissionsPermission {
  id: ID!
  type: String!
  controller: String!
  action: String!
  enabled: Boolean!
  policy: String
  role: UsersPermissionsRole
}

type UsersPermissionsRole {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
  type: String
  permissions(
    sort: String
    limit: Int
    start: Int
    where: JSON
  ): [UsersPermissionsPermission]
  users(
    sort: String
    limit: Int
    start: Int
    where: JSON
  ): [UsersPermissionsUser]
}

type UsersPermissionsUser {
  id: ID!
  created_at: DateTime!
  updated_at: DateTime!
  username: String!
  email: String!
  provider: String
  confirmed: Boolean
  blocked: Boolean
  role: UsersPermissionsRole
}
```

Comment: Whether this is even possible and what queries/mutations you would use entirely depends on the schemas in question and what operations they actually expose, so it's not really clear what you're asking here.

Comment: My assumption is that there are two operations required - read all nodes and then write all nodes. I know how to do the first part, but not sure how to write several nodes at once. The schema of the node is defined above

Comment: Again, any mutations for writing a single node or multiple nodes of a particular reference would be specific to your schema, i.e. there would have to be some kind of field like `createMicrosite` (or `insertMicrosites`, etc.) on your `Mutation` type. Whether a field like that exists and how that field behaves (i.e. allowing you to create many nodes at once vs one at a time) *depends on your schema*. It cannot be implied from the type you've provided.

Comment: Are you asking how to execute multiple mutations in a single operation? Because that I can answer without knowing the schema.

Comment: I added the full schema to the question above